# Setting user-agent in browsers with testcafe

Tags: google-chrome, automated-tests, user-agent, testcafe, web-testing

My e2e UI tests require setting specific user-agent in browsers. It is not a problem in Chrome, because I can use Chrome emulation like `'chrome:emulation:userAgent=...'` but I can't do it with Firefox, Safari, etc.
Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this feature is available only in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

use requestHooks to modify the header request see the link below

https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/creating-a-custom-http-request-hook.html#the-onresponse-method

Comment: how would you go about it?